# Access 2013 VBA: Query recipient email address

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

How do I add the below SQL query AS the recipient of an Outlook email?

```
SELECT 
     E.Email
FROM 
     Employee E
          INNER JOIN ProposalTracking P ON E.Initials = P.UW
```

Here's the VBA code which merely opens a new email in Outlook so far:

```
Private Sub btnEmail_Click()

Dim varName As Variant
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant

varName = "first.last@example.com"

varSubject = "TPS Report"

varBody = "Did you see the memo? We use the new cover sheets now."

DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, , varSubject, varBody, True, False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it through DAO:

```
Dim email as string
Dim sqlSTR as string
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbs as DAO.database
set dbs = currentDB()
sqlSTR = "SELECT E.Email FROM  Employee E INNER JOIN ProposalTracking P ON E.Initials = P.UW"

Set r = dbs.OpenRecordset(Name:=sqlSTR , Type:=dbOpenSnapshot)
varName = r![Email]
r.close
```

Although, if doing it this way, I would add variable in the where clause. It would look like this:

```
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant
Dim email as string
Dim sqlSTR as string
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Dim varInitials as string
Dim dbs as DAO.database

set dbs = currentDB()

varInitials = "P.UW"
sqlSTR = "SELECT E.Email FROM  Employee E INNER JOIN ProposalTracking P ON E.Initials = P.UW WHERE " & someField & " = & " & """" & someVariable & """"

Set r = dbs.OpenRecordset(Name:=sqlSTR , Type:=dbOpenSnapshot)
varName = r![Email]
r.close

varSubject = "TPS Report"

varBody = "Did you see the memo? We use the new cover sheets now."

DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, , , varSubject, varBody, True, False
```

In the sqlSTR, replace someField with whatever your matching is (for example, P.UW) and someVariable with some value you wish to match (e.g. "John"). If it's an int value, remove the & """" from around the someVariable value

Comment: thank you. When I run either of these I get a "Compile error: User-defined type not defined", highlighting "r As DAO.Recordset".

Comment: Add the reference by clicking Tools --> References in the VBA window.

Scroll down until you see Microsoft DAO X.X Object library. Select the highest version and click "OK"

Comment: ok thanks. Next I received a "JOIN expression not supported," so I included parentheses around the ON clause which turned the code from red to black.
But I got the same error again on clicking the button, and now "Set r = dbs.OpenRecordset(Name:=sqlSTR, Type:=dbOpenSnapshot)" is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: You're running this from within Access, so ensure all these tables are housed directly in this application (either linked or local, doesn't matter as long as the name remains the same). 

I didn't review your SQL query. You'll need to update like so:

 sqlSTR = "SELECT E.Email FROM  Employee E INNER JOIN ProposalTracking P ON E.Initials = P.UW WHERE " & someField & " = & " & """" & someVariable & """"


I'll update the above code to reflect

Comment: So far so good, thanks. The next error is "Too few parameters. Expected 1." "Set r = dbs.OpenRecordset(Name:=sqlSTR, Type:=dbOpenSnapshot)" is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Are you using a variable in a WHERE clause?

If so, you'll need to ensure that you're grabbing the field in the SELECT clause. for example if you're looking up P.Name = "John" then you'll have to add P.Name to the SELECT query.

What does your sqlSTR look like?

Comment: Good call, I've removed the WHERE clause since I don't think I need it.
sqlSTR = "SELECT E.Email FROM Employee E INNER JOIN [Proposal Tracking] P ON E.Initials = P.UW"

No more errors; the button does nothing. So now I'm trying to plug pieces of the original VBA code in to see if I can get an Outlook email to open.