# Access 2013: Email GROUPED sections of report to GROUPED BY recipients

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-reports

I need to email sections of a report out of MS Access 2013 based on whom the report is GROUPED BY.

**Best Case:** On Click of a single button, each "UW" would receive only the rows that are assigned to them.
[image]

**Second Best Case:** Each grouped section has a button. On Click of each button, the "UW" that the section is grouped by would receive only the rows that are assigned to them.
[image]

This VBA w/ SQL script from [Access 2013 VBA: Query recipient email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499151/access-2013-vba-query-recipient-email-address/49499409#49499409) allows me to create an Outlook email addressed to a UW, but is not necessarily the UW which the report is grouped by.

```
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant
Dim email as string
Dim sqlSTR as string
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Dim varInitials as string
Dim dbs as DAO.database

set dbs = currentDB()

varInitials = "P.UW"
sqlSTR = "SELECT E.Email FROM  Employee E INNER JOIN ProposalTracking P ON 
E.Initials = P.UW WHERE " & someField & " = & " & """" & someVariable & """"

Set r = dbs.OpenRecordset(Name:=sqlSTR , Type:=dbOpenSnapshot)
varName = r![Email]
r.close

varSubject = "Today's Proposals"

varBody = "Please see the proposals which are assigned to you."

DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, , , varSubject, varBody, True, False
```

How can I email multiple UWs by whom the report is grouped in as few clicks as possible?

Comment: Open recordset of group IDs, looping through recordset, open another recordset of addresses filtered by group, in another loop build an address string for email, open report filtered by the group ID, send email, close report, repeat for next group record.

Comment: @June7 I assumed that I'd be able to Google each item that you've typed here to execute these instructions, but have had no such luck. Would you be willing to please elaborate on how to write this code?

What I'm finding with VBA is that people have many different ways to write code for the same tasks, so Googling for answers has me going around in circles. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Here is example showing opening two recordsets, one dependent on the other. http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=46472&highlight=multiple+email. It does not include the aspect of opening report. You should be able to adapt.